# CSS - Float leave white spaces

Tags: html, css

I try to use some images together and float leaves huge white spaces when I try `margin-top` to make some dent between images.

and by huge white spaces this is what I mean:

[image]

I also tried `clear` or `overflow` but it does`t work.

this is my code:

```css
.product-image-div {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0.2%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}

.product-image {
  transition: .3s ease;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-image-div" style="margin-top: 5%;">
  <img class="product-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/fkSxRCv/p1.png">
</div>
<div class="product-image-div" style="margin-top: 0%;">
  <img class="product-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/fkSxRCv/p1.png">
</div>
<div class="product-image-div" style="margin-top: 5%;">
  <img class="product-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/fkSxRCv/p1.png">
</div>
<div class="product-image-div" style="margin-top: 0%;">
  <img class="product-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/fkSxRCv/p1.png">
</div>
<div class="product-image-div" style="margin-top: 5%;">
  <img class="product-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/fkSxRCv/p1.png">
</div>
<div class="product-image-div" style="margin-top: 0%;">
  <img class="product-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/fkSxRCv/p1.png">
</div>
<div class="product-image-div" style="margin-top: 5%;">
  <img class="product-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/fkSxRCv/p1.png">
</div>
<div class="product-image-div" style="margin-top: 0%;">
  <img class="product-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/fkSxRCv/p1.png">
</div>
<div class="product-image-div" style="margin-top: 5%;">
  <img class="product-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/fkSxRCv/p1.png">
</div>
<div class="product-image-div" style="margin-top: 0%;">
  <img class="product-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/fkSxRCv/p1.png">
</div>
<div class="product-image-div" style="margin-top: 5%;">
  <img class="product-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/fkSxRCv/p1.png">
</div>
<div class="product-image-div" style="margin-top: 0%;">
  <img class="product-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/fkSxRCv/p1.png">
</div>
<div class="product-image-div" style="margin-top: 5%;">
  <img class="product-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/fkSxRCv/p1.png">
</div>
<div class="product-image-div" style="margin-top: 0%;">
  <img class="product-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/fkSxRCv/p1.png">
</div>
<div class="product-image-div" style="margin-top: 5%;">
  <img class="product-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/fkSxRCv/p1.png">
</div>
```

how to solve this problem?

Comment: so you repeat the same question with another account: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60798522/css-float-leave-white-spaces ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `margin-top` you have inlined is your problem. You could hack it and force it to clear? Add `clear:left`.

```
.product-image-div:nth-child(4n+1){
  clear:left;
}
```

Read more on nth-child awesomeness.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score -1):

I think, that you need to use fix height and 'overflow:hidden' for your div's.

```
.product-image-div {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  height: 10vh; //for example
  padding: 0.2%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because those block height is different. Try this css and remove `margin-top: 5%` from div style

```
.product-image-div:nth-child(2n+1) {
    margin-top: 5%;
}
.product-image-div:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```